GAM Regression: Interactions vs Main Effects?
I have a GAM regression model (response is between 0 and 1):
$$ g(\mathbb{E}[Y_i]) = \beta_0 + f_1(t_i, x1_i) + f_2(t_i, x2_i) $$

$g(\cdot)$ is the logit link function $g(p) = \log(\frac{p}{1-p})$
$Y_i$ is a Beta distribution :  $Y_i \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) $
$\beta_0$ is the intercept
$f_1$ and $f_2$ are smooth functions for the interaction effects between:($t$ and $x_1$)
and ($t$ and $x_2$)

Here is the R code for the model:
library(mgcv)
gam_model <- gam(
    y_scaled ~ te(t, x1) + te(t, x2),
    data = sim_data,
    family = betar(link = "logit"),
    method = "REML"
)

My main interests are studying the effects of $X_1$ on $Y$ vs the effects of $X_2$ on $Y$ at different time periods.
As seen this model, it appears to me that I only have the interaction effects in this model.
It seems to me that this might be a problem as per this discussion, it seems that it is unadvisable to have a regression model containing interactions without the main effects:
Including the interaction but not the main effects in a model.
But when I tried to read more about the te functions, e.g. https://r.qcbs.ca/workshop08/book-en/changing-the-basis-function.html , it states:

The function te() is useful when variables are not on the same scale,
and when interactions include main effects. The function ti() is best
for modelling interaction surfaces that do not include the main
effects.

This makes me wonder:

In a GAM regression, if you include interactions, is it obligatory to include the main effects as well?
Does the mgcv::te() function in R by default include the interactions and main effects in the model?



In a GAM regression, if you include interactions, is it obligatory to
include the main effects as well?

Yes, the same arguments as when fitting linear models apply.

Does the mgcv::te() function in R by default include the
interactions and main effects in the model?

According to the documentation "te produces a full tensor product smooth". That includes any main effects and the interaction. If you want to get main effects and interactions separately, you should use marginal smooths: y_scaled ~ ti(t) + ti(x1) + ti(x2) + ti(t, x1) + ti(t, x2). I think I would prefer this in your case because I'm a bit wary of two te smoothers sharing the same marginal effect. I would use te if you included the x1:x2 and the second-order interaction, i.e., y_scaled ~ te(t, x1, x2).

thanks Roland! Just another question: do you know if the s function in mgcv only includes the term once? e.g. s(time, x1) vs te(time,x1) ... I think te(time,x1) includes the main effects of time, the main effects of x1 and the interaction of time and x1.... whereas the s function does not do this?
