Is there a standard way to calculate marginal effects?
My question is about how to set the values of the other predictor variables when calculating the marginal effects for a regression model.
I have a GAM regression model (response is continuous between 0 and 1):
$$ g(\mathbb{E}[Y_i]) = \beta_0 + f_1(t_i, x1_i) + f_2(t_i, x2_i) $$

$g(\cdot)$ is the logit link function $g(p) = \log(\frac{p}{1-p})$
$Y_i$ is a Beta distribution :  $Y_i \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) $
$\beta_0$ is the intercept
$f_1$ and $f_2$ are smooth functions for the interaction effects between:($t$ and $x_1$)
and ($t$ and $x_2$)

Here is the R code for the model:
# note that the te() function supposedly contains the main effects and the interaction effects: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/658558/gam-regression-interactions-vs-main-effects

 library(mgcv)

set.seed(123)

n <- 500
t <- seq(0, 365, length.out = n) 
x1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 10)  
x2 <- rpois(n, lambda = 2)  

true_mean <- function(t, x1, x2) {
    base <- 0.4  
    x1_effect <- 0.003 * x1 * exp(-t/200) 
    x2_effect <- 0.05 * x2 * (1 - exp(-t/200))  
    time_effect <- 0.1 * sin(2 * pi * t/365) 
    return(base + x1_effect + x2_effect + time_effect)
}

y_mean <- true_mean(t, x1, x2)
y <- 100 * plogis(qlogis(y_mean) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.3)) 

sim_data <- data.frame(
    y = y,
    t = t,
    x1 = x1,
    x2 = x2
)

epsilon <- 0.001  
sim_data$y_scaled <- (sim_data$y * (1 - 2 * epsilon) + epsilon) / 100

gam_model <- gam(
    y_scaled ~ te(t, x1) + te(t, x2),
    data = sim_data,
    family = betar(link = "logit"),
    method = "REML"
)

My main interests are studying the effects of $X_1$ on $Y$ vs the effects of $X_2$ on $Y$ at different time periods. E.g. At time=5, did a small change in $X_1$ have a bigger change on the response $Y$ - or did a similar sized small change in $X_2$ have a bigger change in the response $Y$?
My current understanding of marginal effects (ME) are as follows:

Start with the model:
$$ g(\mathbb{E}[Y_i]) = \beta_0 + f_1(t_i, x1_i) + f_2(t_i, x2_i) $$
I observe my data at time points $t* = (t_1, t_2, ... t_n)$. I am interested in calculating the marginal effects at these $n$ observed time points.
The marginal effect at specific values of $t^*$, while holding other variables at their means (i.e. $\bar{X_1}, \bar{X_2}$) , would be:
$$ \text{ME of } x_1: \quad \left.\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}[Y_i]}{\partial x1}\right|_{x1=\bar{x1}, t=t^*, x2=\bar{x2}} =  \left.\frac{\partial g^{-1}(\beta_0 + f_1(t,x1) + f_2(t,\bar{x2}))}{\partial x1}\right|_{x_1=\bar{x_1}, x_2=\bar{x_2} , t=t^*} $$
$$ \text{ME of } x_2: \quad \left.\frac{\partial  \mathbb{E}[Y_i]}{\partial x2}\right|_{x2=\bar{x2}, t=t^*, x1=\bar{x1}} = \left.\frac{\partial g^{-1}(\beta_0 + f_1(t,\bar{x1}) +  f_2(t,x2))}{\partial x2}\right|_{x_1=\bar{x_1}, x_2=\bar{x_2} , t=t^*}$$

I am just wondering about the following question. Take the Marginal Effect for $X_1$ :

At each time point, why don't we use the actual observed value of $X_2$ at that time instead of the average of $X_2$?
Furthermore, why are we taking the average value of $X_1$ at that time instead of the actually observed value of $X_1$ at that time?

For the marginal effects of $X_1$, I thought it would be more informative at each time point $t_i$ to calculate the marginal effects at $(t_i, x_{1i}, x_{2i})$. Yet we clearly don't do this.
Is there some reason for this?

Recap:

Option 1 (Traditional): Marginal effects for $X_1$  calculated at some specific observed time point $t_i$ uses average observed values, i.e. $(t_i, \bar{x_1}, \bar{x_2})$
Option 2: Marginal effects for $X_1$  calculated at some specific observed time point $t_i$ uses actual observed $(t_i, x_{1i}, x_{2i})$

I think that both Option 1 and Option 2 are correct - Option 1 provides a global level marginal effect whereas Option 2 provides a point specific (local level) marginal effect?
Sample interpretations:

Option 1: What's the typical effect on ice cream sales when temperature  increases by 1°F at 2pm, considering our average mix of conditions?
Option 2: What's the effect on ice cream sales when temperature increases by 1°F at 2pm on a specific Wednesday when we had exactly 75°F?



My question is about how to set the values of the other predictor variables when calculating the marginal effects for a regression model.

There are several ways. They lead to identical outcomes in linear models but different outcomes in generalized linear models unless the link function is identity. When the link function is a curve instead of a straight line, the marginal effect depends on the values of all predictors, and prediction at means is unequal to the mean of predictions. See the R and Python package marginaleffects and summary at https://marginaleffects.com/chapters/predictions.html, https://marginaleffects.com/chapters/comparisons.html, and https://marginaleffects.com/chapters/slopes.html.

Marginal effect at the mean. This is your Option 1. Fix the reference point at the mean of each continuous variable and the mode of each categorical variable, or a "mean grid". "This is the slope of the regression equation with respect to the focal predictor, for an individual whose characteristics are exactly average (or modal) on all adjustment variable. As noted in previous chapters, computing estimates at the mean is computationally efficient, but it may not be particularly informative, especially when the perfectly average individual is not realistic or substantively interesting."
Marginal effect at observed values. This is your Option 2, called "unit-level marginal effects" in the website, with predictors fixed at the "empirical grid". Since there are $N$ possible combinations of observed values, "A dataset with one marginal effect estimate per unit of observation is a bit unwieldy and difficult to interpret."
Marginal effect at representative values. Called "slope at user-specified values" and "marginal effect at interesting values" in the website, it fixes predictors at an "interesting grid". Unlike Option 2, these representative values may or may not be directly observed in the data and can be constructed as counterfactual examples that hold particular scientific interest.
Average marginal effect. It also uses the "empirical grid" to compute a slope for every observation at the observed values in the original sample but then average them. As a one-value statistic, "The average marginal effect will be useful when the dataset adequately represents the distribution of predictors in the population, in which case marginalizing across the distribution can give us a good summary of the slopes at different points."
Marginal effect at marginal means. It uses a "balanced grid" that included all unique combinations of categorical variables, while holding numeric variables a their means. "While the balanced grid gives equal weight to each combination of categorical variables, the empirical grid gives more weight to the combinations that are more frequent in the data". This is "particularly useful in experimental contexts, where the sample is not representative of the target population, and where we want to treat each combination of treatment conditions similarly".

These methods are all correct but serve different purposes. Option 3 appears to serve your research interest the best. You would fix both x1 and x2 at several value combinations from a table that represent important situations, vary t across all days in a year, and plot the curve of marginal effects over time by different value combinations. The marginaleffects package supports generalized additive models mgcv::gam().
Your data example, however, indicates that x1 is a continuous predictor whereas x2 is a discrete count. They have different unit of measurements and their marginal effects may not reveal which one is more important. To compare which one has a greater impact on the response, you can use measures that are analogous to the variance accounted for in linear models, which is to use anova() to compare which predictor causes the overall fit (i.e., logLik, deviance, AIC, BIC) to change more when removed.
